# VueJS не рендерит список

Tags: vue.js

Почему это не работает? Список не выводит
Помогите пожалуйста

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Available talks</h3>
    <div v-for="item in items">
      <p>{{item.title}} by <strong>{{item.userId}}</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items:[]
       }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.fetchData();
  },
    methods: {
    fetchData: function () {
    this.$http.get( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function( data ) {
        this.items = data;
    }); } } }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас потеря контекста this в этом месте:

```
this.$http.get( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function( data ) 
{
    this.items = data;
});
```

Можно исправить либо присвоив this другой переменной:

```
var that = this;
this.$http.get( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function( data ) 
{
    that.items = data;
});
```

Либо использовать стрелочную функцию из ES6:

```
this.$http.get( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', (data) => 
{
    this.items = data;
});
```